# CrateDB aggregate all array elements

Tags: sql, cratedb

I am working to aggregate (sum) all returned array values.
The target column contains objects that contains an array of objects.
e.g.

```
Object
- person: "bob"
- children: 
  - zaphod
    - age: 42 
  - ford
    - age: 42
```

In the above example, I attempt an aggregation over the ages like so, to no avail:

```
SELECT SUM(people['children']['age'])
FROM mydatabase
WHERE people IS NOT null
LIMIT 100;
```

The error I see is "UnsupportedFeatureException".
I can accept if this feature is unsupported. But, I am curious if I am simply going about this the wrong way. Can this be done or am I better served managing the data by a downstream process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.6 of CrateDB (released on 2021-07-13) includes a new scalar function [array_sum](https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/master/general/builtins/scalar-functions.html#array-sum-array) which can do this:

```
SELECT ARRAY_SUM(people['children']['age'])
FROM mydatabase
WHERE people IS NOT null
LIMIT 100;
```